# How to copy a specific piece of the post to another page

Tags: posts

Anyone know how to copy specific piece over of the_content(); of post, to another page distinguishing this content by post ID?
I want to copy  some gallery from each post to page gallery. Gallery code:

```
<?php $fields = CFS()->get( 'gallery' );
 foreach ( $fields as $field ) { ?>
<div class="single-row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="single-image-gallery col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <a href="<?php echo $field['add_img']; ?>" class="foobox" rel="gallery">
                <img src="<?php echo $field['add_img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $field['alt1']; ?>">
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="single-image-gallery col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <a href="<?php echo $field['add_img2']; ?>" class="foobox" rel="gallery">
                <img src="<?php echo $field['add_img2']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $field['alt2']; ?>">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="single-image-gallery col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <a href="<?php echo $field['add_img3']; ?>" class="foobox" rel="gallery">
                <img src="<?php echo $field['add_img3']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $field['alt3']; ?>">
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="single-image-gallery col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <a href="<?php echo $field['add_img4']; ?>" class="foobox" rel="gallery">
                <img src="<?php echo $field['add_img4']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $field['alt4']; ?>">
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You could use a reusable block if you have a content fragment you want to appear in multiple places?

Comment: i want to get the same <div> </div> from each posts, but they're have diffrent content. This gallery is make by custom field suite in loop.

Comment: Oh, so it's not actually a part of the post content? You didn't mention the custom fields, can you edit your question so that it contains everything needed to answer it? Including the code that generates the gallery you're wanting to clone?

Comment: Yes, its a part of content, but not inside the loop. This is beyond the loop of posts